# Regex can't escape question mark?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, escaping

I can't match the question mark character although I escaped it.
I tried escaping with multiple backslashes and also using `re.escape()`.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
import re

text = 'test?'
result = ''

result = re.match(r'\?',text)

print ("input: "+text)
print ("found: "+str(result))
```

Output:

```
input: test?
found: None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) only matches a pattern at the begining of string; as in the docs:

> If zero or more characters at the **beginning** of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.

so, either:

```
>>> re.match(r'.*\?', text).group(0)
'test?
```

or [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

```
>>> re.search(r'\?', text).group(0)
'?'
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know what "beginning" of the string meant (when the string contains no spaces) since regex usually matches any position.

Comment: @radry it's not about the regex but it's about the function which uses that regex.